# Is there a way to disable rebasing on a particular branch in Github?

Tags: git, github

We're using Github: FI and we want to have a release branch that is immune from history manipulation / rebasing.  Besides establishing a policy, is there a way, with our current setup, to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think establishing a policy is the best way. With manually-managed git repos you can use a hook (probably pre-receive) to deny non-fast-forward pushes, but I don't believe Github:FI exposes server-side hooks. But a policy and public shaming for any violators is probably going to be effective enough. Besides, a hook would prevent you from force-pushing in the rare event that you, the admin, really do need to "fix up" the branch.